# How to combine outputs of different functions into a nicely report?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, report, r-glue

I have like:
. multiple plots, each created by a distinct function.

```
#Plot 1
sis_name <- babynames %>% 
  filter(name == "Kate", sex == "F") %>% 
  select("year", "name", "prop")

plot1 <- ggplot(data = sis_name) +
             geom_line(mapping = aes(x = year, y = prop)) +
             labs(title = "The Popularity of baby girls' name Kate", x = 
             "Year", y = "Proportion")

#Plot 2
plot2 <- ggplot(data = mydata) +
            geom_point(mapping=aes(x=X, y=Y), color="blue") +
            labs(title="Y vs X")
```

. some "text" outputs, created by glue::glue() and paste() functions.

```
conf_interval <- function(mydata) {
  model <- lm(Y~X, data = mydata)
  B_conf <- confint(model,                       #confidence interval for B
                    model$coefficients[2], 
                    level = 0.95
    glue::glue("Confidence interval for slop is {B_conf}")
}
```

What if I want to create a FUNCTION that calls out all the outputs (plot 1, plot 2, and the confidence interval) and combine them all into ONE nicely formatted report
(i.e. a sequence of plot and glue() commands from all the functions called sequentially)?
The requirement is to call out the report with a "function".
Any suggestions on which functions that I should look at?

Comment: Have you looked into rmarkdown and knitr?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've just had a look a Rmarkdown, it really does help me to combine everything into one nice report.  
However, my assignment requires the report should be called by a "function". Can Rmarkdown be called by a function?? So far, I know using Rmarkdown the report will be saved as a .Rmd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the example below as a file called `report.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Me"
date: "21/08/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)
library(glue)
```

# Title

```{r}
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point()
```

Other variables include `r glue_collapse(colnames(mpg), sep = ", ", last = " and ")`.
````

Subsequently, you can run the following:

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("report.Rmd", html_document())
```

To produce the report.

Comment: Thank you very much teurnbrand! Although it was not exactly what I expected, I've learned new things. Rmarkdown is fancy, very useful, and worth trying.